# Juntar células com python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Estou fazendo um web scraping para pegar dados das melhores ações do dia e juntar numa tabela em um arquivo do excel. Estou tentando pelo código:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())

# Access the website with the most popular stocks
link = 'https://br.investing.com/equities/trending-stocks'
browser.get(link)




import pandas as pd
table = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="trendingInnerContent"]/table').text)
table = table.split(sep='\n')
empty = []
for item in table:
    item = item.split(' ')
    filtered = [x for x in item if x.strip()]
    empty.append(filtered)
   
tb = pd.DataFrame(empty)
tb.to_excel('Atualizado.xlsx', encoding='utf-8', header=False, index = False)
del(empty[0])
```

Porém está separando os nomes em diversas células, queria juntá-los para a tabela ficar certa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, acredito que o que esteja acontecendo seja que o `item` em seu script esteja recebendo o `split(' ')`.

Sendo assim, o resultado para:

```
    Petrobras PN    23,67   23,81   23,47   +0,05   +0,21%  15,74M
```

seria:

```
['', '', '', '', 'Petrobras', 'PN', '', '', '', '23,67', '', '', '', '23,81', '', '', '', '23,47', '', '', '', '+0,05', '', '', '', '+0,21%', '', '', '', '15,74M', '', '', '', '']
```

Logo após vc filtra para a variável `filtered` fazendo o strip

Sua variável filtered está assim:

```
['Petrobras', 'PN', '23,67', '23,81', '23,47', '+0,05', '+0,21%', '15,74M']
```

E é aí que os nomes estão se dividindo.

Partindo do princípio que são sempre 6 índices.

Acho que a solução seria:

```
indices = filtered[-6:]
nome = " ".join(filtered[:-6])
```

Neste caso apresentado, teríamos

```
>>> indices
['23,67', '23,81', '23,47', '+0,05', '+0,21%', '15,74M']

>>> nome
'Petrobras PN'
```

Caso queira colocar tudo junto:

```
tudo_junto = [nome] + indices
```

Resultado

```
>>> tudo_junto
['Petrobras PN', '23,67', '23,81', '23,47', '+0,05', '+0,21%', '15,74M']
```

Comment: Valeu demais cara! Voltei pro python agora, alguns conceitos ficaram meio perdidos.

Answer (score 1):

O método de leitura da tabela em *html* que usa é equivocado pois é verboso, complicado e propício a erros, além de ficar sujeito as especificidades de um módulo muito parrudo e específico para a automação de web browsers, o [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), quando na verdade tudo o que precisa de um web browser é o cabeçalho personificando um agente do usuário, no caso peguei a string no meu próprio navegador Chrome com a url `chrome://version/`.

O [Módulo Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) oferece aos seus usuários uma ferramenta para leitura de tabelas em *HTML*, o método [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) que permite a leitura de um caminho, uma URL ou uma string contendo texto HTML.

Alguns sites somente se permitem serem acessados por determinado [agentes de usuário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent), no caso o site que quer acessar faz essa restrição, impedindo assim ferramentas de automação como `pandas.read_html()` de fazer a leitura direta dos dados.
Para contornar essa limitação é possível utilizar o módulo [`Requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) para acessar o site simulando um navegador conhecido e poder obter o HTML da página.

Para extrair a tabela do HTML use um parser leve com suporte a XPATH, no caso usei o módulo [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/index.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml import html, etree

url = 'https://br.investing.com/equities/trending-stocks'

#User-Agent vai personificar um Chrome mas pode ser outro navegador. X-Requested-With informa que foi feita uma requisiçãocom XMLHttpRequest
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

#Carrega a página com o cabeçalho preparado.
page = requests.get(url, headers=header)
#Faz a análise do HTML e busca uma tabela específica via XPATH. 
table = html.fromstring(page.content).xpath(r'//*[@id="trendingInnerContent"]/table')[0]
#Retorna somente a tabela ao texto HTML original e cria o dataframe. 
df = pd.read_html(etree.tostring(table))
print(df)
```

Resultando:

```
[    Unnamed: 0                 Nome  Último  Máxima  Mínima Variação   Var. %     Vol.   Hora  Unnamed: 9
0          NaN             Ambev ON    1621    1633    1600    +0,03   +0,19%   22,16M  07/05         NaN
1          NaN               Weg ON    3342    3399    3306     -031   -0,92%   10,12M  07/05         NaN
2          NaN          Petrorio ON    1921    1922    1867    +0,01   +0,05%   13,96M  07/05         NaN
3          NaN         Petrobras PN    2438    2445    2346    +0,88   +3,74%   73,69M  07/05         NaN
4          NaN   Banco do Brasil ON    2994    3048    2976    +0,73   +2,50%   26,70M  07/05         NaN
5          NaN              Rumo ON    2134    2139    2070    +0,64   +3,09%    6,47M  07/05         NaN
6          NaN            Gafisa ON     451     451     436    +0,15   +3,44%    4,08M  07/05         NaN
7          NaN           Neogrid ON     707     720     705    +0,02   +0,28%    1,67M  07/05         NaN
8          NaN       Met. Gerdau PN    1620    1642    1587     -005   -0,31%    9,15M  07/05         NaN
9          NaN     Itau Unibanco PN    2763    2770    2724    +0,33   +1,21%   26,59M  07/05         NaN
10         NaN         JHSF Part ON     731     745     717    +0,19   +2,67%   11,26M  07/05         NaN
11         NaN           Triunfo ON     465     475     410    +0,56  +13,69%   11,62M  07/05         NaN
12         NaN             CTEEP PN    2556    2563    2535    +0,22   +0,87%    1,08M  07/05         NaN
13         NaN                Oi ON     177     180     169    +0,06   +3,51%   79,78M  07/05         NaN
14         NaN  Lojas Americanas ON    1924    1954    1864     -019   -0,98%    7,72M  07/05         NaN
15         NaN              Vale ON   11545   11655   11419    +0,40   +0,35%   21,60M  07/05         NaN
16         NaN          Klabin Unit    2790    2801    2745     -005   -0,18%    4,49M  07/05         NaN
17         NaN        J B Duarte PN     330     336     303     -002   -0,60%  102,40K  07/05         NaN
18         NaN         C&A Modas ON    1247    1253    1221    +0,20   +1,63%  856,70K  07/05         NaN
19         NaN            Itausa PN    1034    1034    1016    +0,14   +1,37%   23,88M  07/05         NaN
20         NaN            TAEE UNIT    3885    3924    3819     -033   -0,84%    3,11M  07/05         NaN
21         NaN          Hercules PN    1056    1079    1030    +0,19   +1,83%    2,60K  07/05         NaN
22         NaN        Via Varejo ON    1216    1231    1200    +0,20   +1,67%   25,89M  07/05         NaN
23         NaN      BR Malls Par ON    1061    1083    1034    +0,29   +2,81%   21,78M  07/05         NaN
24         NaN               JBS ON    3118    3118    2980    +0,54   +1,76%    7,37M  07/05         NaN
25         NaN      Lojas Renner ON    4356    4357    4176    +1,74   +4,16%    9,84M  07/05         NaN
26         NaN    Magazine Luiza ON    1989    1990    1933    +0,43   +2,21%   23,14M  07/05         NaN
27         NaN        Portobello ON    1201    1212    1152    +0,26   +2,21%    2,52M  07/05         NaN
28         NaN         Sanepar Unit    2064    2066    2037    +0,34   +1,67%  905,60K  07/05         NaN
29         NaN        Neoenergia ON    1675    1702    1651    +0,49   +3,01%    4,24M  07/05         NaN]
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Google Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/juntarcelulas#main.py)</sup>